# Coded Web Performance Test using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, performance-testing

I am trying to create a series of web tests for performance testing. 
For every test class which is inherited from ThreadedWebTest, I would have a series of requests. 
There are a group of settings which is being used in all of the tests and I would like to place them in just one class for example what I want to do is to put the login and logout into a separate class call them in every other test.

```
Me.BeginTransaction("Login")
For Each r As WebTestRequest In IncludeWebTest(New LoadTests.Requests.Login(), False)
     MyBase.Send(r)
Next
Me.EndTransaction("Login")
```

Is there a better way for accomplishing this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I created a module and stored the common variables values such as username, password, server url and so on. 
and for calling the list of requests I employed following generic piece of code:

```
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.Proxy = Settings.Proxy
        Me.ServerURL = Settings.ServerURL
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Run()
        RunWebTest(New Login)
        RunWebTest(New CustomerCreate)
        RunWebTest(New CustomerDelete)
        RunWebTest(New Logout)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RunWebTest(Of WebTestType)(test As WebTestType)
        For Each r As WebTestRequest In IncludeWebTest(GetType(WebTestType).GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {}), False)
            MyBase.Send(r)
        Next
    End Sub
```